# Simple_form: How to set f.input with with boolean values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

In DB, I have a `boolean` column, let's call it `morning`.

In a view, this is how I display a select box menu:

```
  = f.input :morning, label: false, required: true, collection: [["Yes", true], ["No", false]], input_html: { class: "..." }
```

However, when I send this form, nothing will be saved to DB.

If I try modify it, like this:

```
  = f.input :morning, label: false, required: true, collection: ["Yes", "No"], input_html: { class: "..." }
```

Same thing happens.

What's the correct way of setting a select box with `true/false` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with the values in collection, but with input type.

```
<%= f.input :morning, as: :select, collection: [['Yes',true], ['No',false]], required: true, include_blank: false %>
```

Something like this. Just pay attention to: `as: :select`